# How to display multiple charts with varying x-scales side by side in Vega

Tags: vega

I have a set of charts with the same y-scale but varying x-scales. I am using `hconcat` to display them side by side. In order to conserve space and avoid repetition, I have disabled the y-axis for all but the first chart. However, this is causing the title of the first chart to offset:

[image]

[This is a link to a Vega Editor.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

As the blue circle indicates, the two titles, "Chain" and "Mini Invaders," are not in line. Is there a way to fix this?

I have tried to express these charts using `facet` but as far as I can tell, facets do not permit varying x-scales. However, please do let me know if this is somehow possible with facets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need labelBound: true in your spec.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

```
{
  "config": {
    "view": {
      "continuousWidth": 400,
      "continuousHeight": 300,
      "stroke": "#000000",
      "strokeOpacity": 1,
      "strokeWidth": 2
    },
    "axis": {"labelFontSize": 24, "titleFontSize": 24,  "labelBound":true},
    "legend": {"labelFontSize": 24, "labelLimit": 0, "titleFontSize": 32},
    "title": {"baseline": "bottom", "fontSize": 24}
  },
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "area", "clip": true, "opacity": 0.2},
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "field": "Variations",
              "legend": {
                "orient": "top",
                "symbolOpacity": 1,
                "symbolSize": 200,
                "symbolStrokeWidth": 3,
                "symbolType": "stroke"
              },
              "scale": {
                "domain": ["Original Algorithm"],
                "range": [
                  "#e41a1c",
                  "#377eb8",
                  "#4daf4a",
                  "#984ea3",
                  "#a65628",
                  "#646464"
                ]
              },
              "type": "nominal"
            },
            "x": {"field": "step", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "axis": {"labels": true, "tickCount": 5, "title": null},
              "field": "lower",
              "type": "quantitative"
            },
            "y2": {"field": "upper"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "clip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "color": {"field": "Variations", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {"field": "step", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "regret",
              "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
              "type": "quantitative"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "height": 200,
      "title": "Chain",
      "transform": [{"filter": "(datum.domain === 'Chain')"}],
      "width": 200
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "area", "clip": true, "opacity": 0.2},
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "field": "Variations",
              "legend": {
                "orient": "top",
                "symbolOpacity": 1,
                "symbolSize": 200,
                "symbolStrokeWidth": 3,
                "symbolType": "stroke"
              },
              "scale": {
                "domain": ["Original Algorithm"],
                "range": [
                  "#e41a1c",
                  "#377eb8",
                  "#4daf4a",
                  "#984ea3",
                  "#a65628",
                  "#646464"
                ]
              },
              "type": "nominal"
            },
            "x": {"field": "step", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "axis": {"labels": false, "tickCount": 5, "title": null},
              "field": "lower",
              "type": "quantitative"
            },
            "y2": {"field": "upper"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "clip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "color": {"field": "Variations", "type": "nominal"},
            "x": {"field": "step", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {
              "field": "regret",
              "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
              "type": "quantitative"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "height": 200,
      "title": "Mini Invaders",
      "transform": [{"filter": "(datum.domain === 'Mini Invaders')"}],
      "width": 200
    }
```

[image]